# filter bank of gabor filters with different frequencies and orientations

Tags: filters, stft, gabor

I was reading a paper which uses a filter bank of gabor filters with different frequencies and **orientations**. However, I often see the construction of a filter bank of gabor filters with different frequencies and **scales**.

I am not sure on the construction of it. How do I construct it, any generic example will be ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter The $\theta$ controls the orientation.

Comment: Is this a form of short time fourier transform?